# tabularray with longtblr, over duplex printing

Tags: double-sided, tabularray

I am creating a form which needs to have an overleaf page of notes on the rear of the first page only. So to be in the correct format, there must be a blank page on every odd page except for the first so that it prints correctly.

The form is filled with JSON data and pre-processed by Jinja2, so as an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}{ colspec = {|X|X|}, rowhead = 1, rowfoot = 1} 
\hline
header & header \\
\BLOCK{ for item in products }
\VAR{item.description} & \VAR{item.cost}\\ % Jinja2 will turn this into a long list of items
\BLOCK{ endfor }
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

So this for loop can span any number of pages, but I need it to skip every odd/even page so that when printed out in duplex format, it prints correctly
(first page -> overleaf notes -> second page -> blank -> third page -> blank ...

Thanks for your help, any suggestions or even a complete rethink of how to do it would be super appreciated

Comment: Maybe locally save `\newpage` as `\oldnewpage` and redefine `\newpage` as `\oldnewpage\oldnewpage`?

Comment: How would you go about putting a ```\newpage``` in the middle of a longtblr/longtable? I've tried to ```\newpage```, ```\vfill```, and ```\vspace{\fill}``` inside the table so that it skips ahead a page but it breaks the table

Comment: I have written an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) internally uses `\newpage` command to break pages, we may redefine the command to get what we want:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=8cm,paperheight=5cm,width=7cm,height=4.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\let\oldnewpage=\newpage
\def\firstnewpage{\oldnewpage overleaf notes\oldnewpage}
\def\othernewpage{\oldnewpage\hbox{}\oldnewpage}

\begin{document}
Odd Page \newpage
\begingroup
\def\newpage{\firstnewpage\let\newpage=\othernewpage}
\begin{longtblr}{ colspec = {|X|X|}, rowhead = 1, rowfoot = 1} 
\hline
Header & Header \\
\hline
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
item.description & item.cost \\
\hline
Footer & Footer \\
\hline
\end{longtblr}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ChrisMacdonald Then you may accept this answer by clicking the check mark in the top left corner.

Comment: @L.J.R., its amazing ^^